# outlook.com, custom domain, two factor, exchange

Tags: exchange, outlook.com

I am trying to add my outlook.com account with a custom domain to my Apple Mail client. I was able to successfully add the account to my iPhone using the "outlook.com" account template provided in iOS. In OSX Mavericks, there is no such template so I started with the Exchange account type.

However, it won't accept my device passwords no matter what I try. I tried different servers, `outlook.com`, `m.outlook.com`. I regenerated the device password each time, making sure that I was copying the exact password etc, so I am fairly sure that I got it right.

I also tried following the instructions here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/exchange-activesync-eas-settings-for-outlook-2013/55ae6703-8ebd-4bf2-b702-989ff7269a80

but it did not help at all.

What am I missing here? I never tried adding the account to my Mac before enabling two factor authentication, so I can't really say if that is the culprit.

Comment: You want to be careful depending on this feature as it is rapidly running out of life: http://www.liveside.net/2014/04/11/one-of-the-last-vestiges-of-windows-live-admin-center-stumbles-to-the-deadpool/

Comment: Wow that sucks! I just migrated from Google when they shut down their service. That might be why I can't register new devices. Maybe I'll end up having to host my own email like back in the days.